# AWS CodeBuild error while build project => YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Runtime version selection is not supported by this build image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I trying to build Docker image using AWS CodeBuild

I follow AWS codebuild sample below
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html

below is what i did.

I write buildspec.yml like this.(exactly same as what I saw as previous link)
[buildspec.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRSh3.png)

and I start build project using aws CodeBuild, but I got this *Codebuild Log* error message :

[image: Codebuild Log]

**YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Runtime version selection is not supported by this build image.** <== this message means what? 
Is any other docker runtime version except 18? what should I do?

please help...

Comment: Which version of YAML are you using, and what runtime version is specified therein?

Comment: @C.Peck I edited this post. insert screenshot of buildspec.yml , version yaml file : 0.2, runtime version : 18

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For aws/codebuild/standard:2.0 images you must specify a runtime-versions in your buildspec. Sample here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-runtime-versions.html

Also note that since your build needs docker access inside the build container, you will need to enable the privileged mode for your CodeBuild project.

Comment: I specify runtime-versions as I posted ( please see my buildspec.yml image link), and I change privileged mode to true, but I got same result.

Comment: You don't have your CodeBuild project configuration mentioned here. Can you confirm you are using "aws/codebuild/standard:2.0" and not some other build image? Runtime-versions in buildspec is only supported by the standard:2.0 image or later versions (when they become available).

Comment: thanks, I solved this issue after privileged mode to true.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the following error after fixing.

```
2019/10/06 00:21:59 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: 
Runtime version selection is not supported in version 0.1, see documentation
```

Solution:

After putting a lot of effort in this issue I realized it was the version on the top which needs correction. I was changing the ubuntu image version but The version at the top of the `buildspec.yml`  needs to be changed.

- below version needs to be changed in buildspec YAML file

```
     version: 0.2
      phases:
        install:
         runtime-versions:
         docker: 18
```

Comment: Yes. Top level version "version: 0.1" needs to be changed to "version: 0.2"

Answer (score 0):

While trying with Gradle for Spring Boot project,

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
  build:
    commands:
      - bash ./gradlew clean build
artifacts:
  files:
    - build/libs/codecommitdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    - appspec.yml
    - scripts/*
  discard-paths: yes
```